# Diode questions

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

I need to replace a diode on my GCM harness and have a few questions.

1. Does a diodes reverse conductivity depend only on the voltage applied to the diode or is current a factor as well?  I know current is a function of voltage in a diode so does that answer my question?
2. There are 2 numbers on the diode I need to replace:
   (1N4007 and NTELI84F) from what I can tell the first is specifications for the diode and the second I am not sure?

I have searched 1N4007 and found that to describe diodes with a 1000V breakdown voltage and 1Amp max current.

3. Do I only need to worry about the 1000V breakdown and 1Amp max when replacing this diode?

Thanks

Comment: What is a "GCM harness"?

Comment: What;s GCM? And do you have a picture of this NTELI84F (which clearly shows the markings on the device)?

Comment: General Control Module.  I have a harness with some diodes in it for protection against inductive loads.  Its just a series of wires for the I/O of the module.  @Elliot Alderson

Comment: The NTELI84F is one of the tags on the diode itself, along with 1N4007.  I do not know what the NTELI84F tag is, like a serial number or something?  I do have a picture but since the diode is small its hard to read.  @Huisman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse breakdown voltage must be greater than the maximum reverse voltage that will be applied to the diode.

The 1N4007 is one of a series of 1 amp diodes numbered 1N4001 - 1N4007, with increasing reverse voltage ratings as the numbers increase.  It is common to specify the 1N4007,  even if that voltage rating is not required, as there is little price difference between the lowest and highest rated diode in that series, and no harm in having a higher-than-needed reverse voltage rating.

Comment: I don't see how this answers OP questions. This is general information. Or do you implicitely suggest to replace the diode by the same type and rating? Maybe to make it explicit?